# Object instance still accessible after destruction

Tags: c++, oop, struct, destructor

I have an `Animal` struct that has `Dog` struct as a data member, my question is why the `Dog` instance that is created (inside the `Animal`) is still accessible through the allocated instance of `Animal` even after the `Dog` is destroyed (as shown in the output)

```
struct Dog {
    Dog() {}
    Dog(std::string n) : name(n) {std::cout << "dog constructed\n";}
    ~Dog() {std::cout << "dog destructed\n";}

    std::string name;
};

struct Animals {
    Animals() {std::cout << "animal constructed\n";}
    ~Animals() {std::cout << "animal destructed\n";}

    Dog dog;
};

Animals*    foo() {
    Animals*    animals = new Animals;
    animals->dog = Dog("layka");
    return animals;
}

int main() {
    Animals*    animals = foo();
    std::cout << animals->dog.name << std::endl;
    delete animals;
}
```

Output:

```
animal constructed
dog constructed
dog destructed
layka
animal destructed
dog destructed
```

Also could someone please explain why animal is destroyed before the dog? and why it's destroyed twice while only constructed once?

I wasn't expecting `dog.name` to have the same value after it has been destroyed

Comment: If you have an object that has passed its life-time, that has been destructed, you simply should not allow the code you use that object any more. If the code allows it, then it has *undefined behavior*.

Comment: With that said, I think you misunderstand the *copying* that happens with the assignment `animals->dog = Dog("layka")`. You create a temporary `Dog` object, it gets copied into `animals->dog`, then the temporary object is destructed. The copy still lives on.

Comment: okay but why the copy still lives on, isn't it created on the stack? I know it's part of the allocated `animal` object, but (I think) that isn't enough for the `dog` object to have its lifetime extended.

Comment: The object that `animals` is pointing to have its own `Dog` object. As long as this `Animals` object is alive, its embedded `Dog` object is alive. You copy the temporary `Dog` object into this `animals->dog` object. And because you create that `Animals` object on the heap, all its embedded member variables and object are *also* stored on the heap. They are included in the `Animals` object itself.

Comment: Lets take another example: `struct A { int d; };`. Now you do `A* a = new A; a->d = 5;`. Would you consider the value `5` disappearing from the `A` object that `a` is pointing to? It's really the same thing if the member is an instance of a class (an object).

Answer (score 0):

1. animal constructed
2. dog constructed: some temporary `Dog("layka")` started construction and its copy
   stored in `animals->dog`
3. dog destructed: some dog that constructed in `Dog("layka")` started destruction
   but `animals->dog` is alive along with its name.
4. layka
5. animal destructed: start of Animal destructor but not its end
6. dog destructed: start of `animals->dog` destructor

Animal not destructed before `animals->dog` it simply started destructor first. Example below shows what happens in destructor of Animal:

```
~Animals() { 
        std::cout << "animal destructed\n"; //animal still exist
        std::cout << "dog destructed\n";// animals.dog still exist
        //destroys animals.dog.name
        //destroys whole animals.dog
        //animal exist but animals->dog no more
        //destroys whole animal
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"Order of output is not order of destruction"_?

Comment: okay but why the copy is still alive along with its name, isn't it created on the stack? I know it's part of the allocated animal object, but (I think) that isn't enough for the dog object to have its lifetime extended.

Comment: Copy of dog in animals->dog is not a reference to dog created in Dog("layka") it's totally new dog and has its own life time.